# Clarification on covariance matrix for multidimensional Gaussian distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, covariance, covariance-matrix

It is a well known property of Gaussian distributions that if $Y = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$, where each $Y_i$ is a real Gaussian random variable, then the components of $Y$ are independent if and only if the covariance matrix of $Y$ is diagonal. I would like to clarify how this property generalizes to situations where each $Y_i$ is itself a random vector.

Let $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ be a random variable where each $X_i$ is itself a cenetered $m$-dimensional Gaussian random variable for $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

For each $X_i$ denote its covariance matrix by $\Sigma_{ii}$. Then the $pq$-th element in $\Sigma_{ii}$ is given by $E[(X_i)_p(X_i)_q]$.

For $i \neq j$ the cross covariance matrix is denoted $\Sigma_{ij}$, and its $pq$-th element is given by $E[(X_i)_p(X_j)_q]$.

The covariance matrix for $X$ is now a block matrix $\Sigma$:
$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} & \cdots &\Sigma_{1n} \\ \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\ \Sigma_{n11} & \Sigma_{n2} & \cdots &\Sigma_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$$
with $\Sigma_{ij}$ as above.

In order for the components of $X_i$ to be independent, do we require $\Sigma$ to be diagonal as a block matrix (that is, we only require $\Sigma_{ij} = 0$ for $i \neq j$) or that $\Sigma$ is actually diagonal (that is, we also require each $\Sigma_{ii}$ to be diagonal)?